# Changing history in Github

Tags: git, github, maintainability

I'm learning Github and had a problem.

I was finishing up for the day and I pushed code to a repository.
I then realized I had commented out code no longer needed.
I realize this is bad style so deleted it and pushed again.

It looks kind of strange now having the same commit message twice in a row.

What should/could have been done?
Should I have pushed again and made the message "minor" or "removed commented out code".

I don't want to clutter the history.

Is there a way to completely delete a push's history (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: You can always go back to that commit, `amend` it, and the force push `git push -f`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could've done a `git reset HEAD --hard`, removed the comments, committed the final version and force pushed them (using `git push -f origin branchname`) so that you would have a single commit for all the changes, instead of two.

However, I wouldn't recommend the above, commits are not at all costly in git. Instead, a better commit message, something like `git commit -m "removed commented chunks of code"` for the second commit would have left you with a cleaner history in this case. *IMO, the problem here is not multiple commits, but bad commit message* for the second commit.

I would suggest you alter the commit message of the second commit you made using `git commit --amend` and doing a forced push for the branch after that.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize this is bad style so deleted it and pushed again.

**You have 2 options here:**

1. Replace and commit the new code on top of the old code
2. Delete the old code from the repository.

---

Option 2 means ***`rebase`*** which is a destructive if you are not the only one who use this branch.

So since you already pushed the branch you don't have too many option and you will have to change the code and commit it again.

---

> Is there a way to completely delete a push's history (or whatever it's called)?

**Main options:**

1. revert
2. rebase

### ***`revert`***

Revert will undo your changes.
Revert is not destructive since it does not alter the history, its adding a new **undo** commit on top of the current history

```
git revert <SHA-1>
```

### ***`rebase`***

As mentioned above - a destructive action which will later your history and you want to avoid it since you have published your branch to remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bigger history rewrite jobs to do, check `git rebase -i OLD_COMMIT..HEAD` or similar.

But please note *that when you `push -f` to a github branch* you have to inform all users of that branch. That also holds for any shared repository. As github is mainly for sharing code, keep in mind that you may need to inform all developers, who push to a shared branch, that you changed the history.